# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException The application encountered an unhandled system exception. From binary file

Tags: web-services, dynamics-gp, soapexception

I have a project in .net that accesses a GP Web Services, it works fine. However when I generate a dll from this project and try to run the same from a different project using this dll, I get the following message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException The application encountered an unhandled system exception.  Contact your system administrator for details.

I think it might be a permissions issue or something like this but I'm not sure, this is how the client is created:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();

EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("..."), new UpnEndpointIdentity("..."), (AddressHeader[])null);
DynamicsGPClient wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGPClient(binding, ep);
```